# How to update data within a tensor flow dataset tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have some data (x,y,m) where x and y are tensors with respective dimensions (n x m) and (n x 1) (x is the data and y is the label). The data x comes in two types and the binary tensor m (n x 1) specifies which type each data point is from.

When training my model, I wish to randomly alternate between batches of type 0 or type 1 data. To do this I split the dataset into two:

```
#create initial dataset
init_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y,m))
#split dataset into two (based on m)
m0 = init_data.filter(lambda x,y,m : tf.math.equal(m,0) )
m1 = init_data.filter(lambda x,y,m : tf.math.equal(m,1) )
```

Sometimes the number of points of type 1 or 0 is not very numerous. For my training it does not matter if a batch contains the same datapoint multiple times (only that the batches are chosen randomly at each training epoch). To address this I run:

```
#batch size for training epochs
batch_size = 100 
#large buffer size for shuffling
n = 1000

#shuffle and batch the dataset (allow repeats of datapoints)
m0 = m0.repeat().shuffle(n).batch(batch_size)
m1 = m1.repeat().shuffle(n).batch(batch_size)
```

I can now randomly choose between which of the two datasets I get my batch from at each training epoch using the following:

```
#dataset to sample from at each training iteration
traindat = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([m0,m1], [0.5, 0.5])
```

In psuedo-code my training loop looks as follows:

```
#create an iterator over the dataset
it = iter(traindat)

#train for t iterations
for t in range(T):
    #sample batch
    mysample,labels = next(it)
    #forward pass
    pred = my_NN(my_sample)
    #loss
    loss = my_loss(pred,labels)
    #gradient step
    my_NN.update_via_autograd
```

My problem is as follows:

Suppose that each time I complete 10% of my training loop I want to replace my data (x,y,m) with the neural networks prediction at that iteration i.e. (pred,y,m)?

To do this I currently just overwrite the init_data dataset by adding the line:

```
if t%(t//10) == 0: 
    init_data =tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((pred,y,m))
```

and then run all the previous lines of code again to regenerate traindat and it. However, this seems grossly inefficient. Is there a better way to do this? Many thanks for any help.

Comment: That depends on what you have in `my_func`. To save time for both you and who's trying to answer this, please post a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @thushv89 I have updated my question as you have pointed out.

Comment: From what I know, there's very little room (if not none) to manipulate the dataset, the way you want. Do you have to use tf.data API ? Is there anything stopping you from using plain numpy/pandas?

Comment: I am utilizing the tensorflow dataset for performance reasons (as I am training on a Nvidia Geforce GPU). See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance.